# URL points to different places

Tags: apache-2.2, domain-name-system

designer-school.com points to my root website but www.designer-school.com points to the correct folder.

This is my virtualhost file

```
NameVirtualHost *:80

<VirtualHost *:80>

DocumentRoot /var/www/html/main
ServerName www.joshhornby.co.uk

</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot /var/www/html/designerschool
ServerName http://www.designer-school.com

</VirtualHost>
```

And my DNS settings

http://cl.ly/image/2m2o442r393K

Shouldn't they both point to the same place?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a ServerAlias for designer-school.com, because right now, the ONLY thing Apache will return for that Vhost is www.designer-school.com:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot /var/www/html/designerschool
ServerName http://www.designer-school.com
ServerAlias designer-school.com

</VirtualHost>
```